# NSClient++ not getting installed in windows

Tags: windows, linux, nagios

I have installed Nagios monitoring tool in linux whose service is running successfully as expected.

Now as per NSClient documentation, the windows part is not getting installed.
The required steps are:

```
(a) Copy pNSClient.exe, pdh.dll, psapi.dll and counters.defs in any directory on the machine you want to monitor. ie. (c:\nsclient).
(b) Open a dos prompt in the installation directory
(c) Run the following command : >pNSClient.exe /install
(d) Type 'net start nsclient' on the command line or start the service 'Nagios Agent' in the services applet of the control panel.
```

The installation will create an entry for the service in the registry and create a new key to store parameters. The created key is the following:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NSClient**

---

The issue is with the installation as per the first step, and the 'net start nsclient' command is not executing on command prompt, its showing **service name invalid**

Any help regarding this ? M installing this on windows 7.
Only the windows installation part of NSClient is remaining yet the linux part is properly installed along with the 'check_nt' plugin.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSClient is antiquated and deprecated. You should be using [NSClient++](http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/) (AKA nscp), which has an actual installer, along with [excellent documentation](http://www.nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/doc).

Alternatively, if you are dealing with more than a few dozen Windows hosts, and are using Active Directory, you might want to consider [Nagios-WSC](http://nagios-wsc.sourceforge.net/). Whether or not it will suit your needs depends on what sort of checks you are hoping to do, though.

Answer (score 1):

That documentation might be out of date. Try using the following doc to install NSClient++. The doc is for Nagios XI, but the agent instructions should be the same.
http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Installing_The_XI_Windows_Agent.pdf

Otherwise, you could also try:

```
  net start nsclient++
```

Answer (score 0):

just an advice - forget about manual installs )
install choco

```
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

restart powershell session and 
install nsclient++

```
choco install nscp
```